# Question on creating templates in coderush

Tags: templates, coderush

I am looking to start creating some CR templates to fit with my style of coding (such is the power of coderush).

I tried a dummy one yesterday and made an auto prop with two fields, one for the type and one for the name.

This worked as expected with one flaw...

In coderush when I expand a built in template it sets the cursor to the first field. Mine does not, It sets the cursor at the end of the line

```
Private <<Field(Type)>> <<Field(Name)>> {get; set}
```

PS: Does anyone know how to type out those teeny tiny angle brackets that they use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To initialize the caret position, use the **Caret** [text command](http://www.skorkin.com/2011/01/dxcore-text-commands-list/). To perform the selection, utilize the **BlockAnchor** text command in coalition with the **Caret** text command. As a result, your template will look similar to this one:

```
Private «Caret»«Field(Type)»«BlockAnchor» «Field(Name)» {get; set}
```

P.S. I'm pasting the template expansion right from the CodeRush Templates Editor, so they are pasted as is. To type those characters here, simply specify their HTML name, for example "laquo" (left double angle quotes) preceeding with & and followed by ; characters (e.g. "& laquo ;"), remove spaces and get this character: «

Answer (score 2):

Those characters **«** and **»** are used to denote:

- Textcommands: **«MyTextCommand»**
- StringProviders: **«?MyStringProvider»**
- Aliases:: **«:MyOtherTemplate»**

Text commands are available from a dropdown list just underneath the main expansion window.

All 3 Token types are available from menu items on the expansion box's context menu.

There should be no need to type these characters manually.

That said, I do prefer to be able to do this and have configured a 3rd party tool [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) to autoreplace **>>** with **»** and **<<** with **«** as I type

FWIW the configuration I use is

```
:*?:<<::«
:*?:>>::»
```

Comment: Cheers Rory :) I'm about to go all kungfoo on templates :)